# why images are duplicated (Picasso)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, picasso

In my code I am using recylcer view trying to show some data.

It's always images are messed up after scrolling.

Here some of my code.

```
public class LeaderBoardAdapter extends UltimateViewAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Profile> mProfilesList;
    private BaseActivity mBaseActivity;

    public LeaderBoardAdapter(final BaseActivity pBaseActivity, final List<Profile> pProfilesList) {
        mProfilesList = pProfilesList;
        mBaseActivity = pBaseActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder pHolder, final int position) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) pHolder;

       holder.paginationTextView.setText(mProfilesList.get(position).getPosition() + ".");
        holder.nameTextView.setText(mProfilesList.get(position).getProfile().getName());

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mProfilesList.get(position).getProfile().getImage())) {
            Picasso
                    .with(mBaseActivity)
                    .load(mProfilesList.get(position).getProfile().getImage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar)
                    .error(R.drawable.default_avatar)
                    .into(holder.userImageView);
        } else {
            holder.userImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_edit_profile_button);
        }

        if (position == 0 || position == 1 || position == 2) {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(mBaseActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(mBaseActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white_transparent));
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getAdapterItemCount() {
        return mProfilesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mProfilesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(View view) {
        return new UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.leaders_board_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public long generateHeaderId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.leaders_board_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    }

    class ViewHolder extends UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder {

        TextView paginationTextView;
        TextView nameTextView;
        TextView securityIndexValueTextView;
        CircularImageView userImageView;
        ImageView securityIndexImageView;
        LinearLayout layout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            paginationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.leaders_board_item_pagination_text_view);
            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.leaders_board_item_name_text_view);
            securityIndexValueTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.leaders_board_item_security_index_value_text_view);
            userImageView = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.leaders_board_item_user_image_view);
            securityIndexImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.leaders_board_item_security_index_image_view);
            layout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.leaders_board_item_layout);
        }

    }
}
```

WHat is wrong here could anyone tell me that ?

Answer (score 3):

You failed to take viewholder recycling into account. What you need is something like

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mProfilesList.get(position).getProfile().getImage())) {
    Picasso.with(mBaseActivity)
           .load(mProfilesList.get(position).getProfile().getImage())
           .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar)
           .error(R.drawable.default_avatar)
           .into(holder.userImageView);
} else {
        // Cancel any pending requests to load an image into the imageview
        Picasso.with(mBaseActivity).cancelRequest(holder.userImageView);
        // Set the imageview to the default avatar
        holder.userImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_avatar);
        holder.userImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_edit_profile_button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) pHolder;
```

This line makes me think you are implementation has problem.
You shouldnt need it to cast it.

Please check for basic examples.

Another problem may be Picasso would use cache mechanism. As i remember there should be method to prevent it.

If you can post your full adapter code, we can check more

Good luck there

Comment: I am using ultimaterecylerview